# Date Comparison in Shell Script doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, date

I know there are some other questions with similar topic. But the solutions doesn't work for me. The following code should compare timestamps from two .csv files. But the comparison doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
input1="/home/seconion/Desktop/DatasetAnalyse/BYOD/alertTimeConverted.csv"
input2="/home/seconion/Desktop/DatasetAnalyse/BYOD/gt_byodTimeConverted.csv"
while IFS=',' read -r timestamp1 msg1 proto1 srcIP1 srcPort1 dstIP1 dstPort1
do
    echo "next alert"
    while IFS=',' read -r timestamp21 timestamp22 duration2 proto2 srcIP2 srcPort2 dstIP2 dstPort2 iflags2 uflags2 riflags2 ruflags2 pkt2 rpkt2 oct2 roct2 app2 entropy2 rentropy2 label2 category12 category22 comments2
    do
        alertTime=$(date -d "$timestamp1" +"%H%M%S%N")
        streamTimeStart=$(date -d "$timestamp21" +"%H%M%S%N")
        streamTimeEnd=$(date -d "$timestamp22" +"%H%M%S%N")

        if [ $streamTimeStart -lt $alertTime ] && [ $alertTime -lt $streamTimeEnd ];
            then echo "true"
        fi
    done < "$input2"
done < "$input1"
```

Comment: Can you let us know some sample values for `streamTimeStart`,`streamTimeEnd` and `alertTime`?

Comment: this is the format: 223445248591000

Comment: Are you using `GNU date`, can you check `date --version`?

Comment: its GNU coreutils 8.21

Comment: It looks incorrect to be in epoch format.

Comment: i am new in bash scripting so what does it mean ?

Comment: Add real examples from `$timestamp1`, `$timestamp21` and `$timestamp22`  to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this format

```
alertTime=$(date -d "$timestamp1" +"%H%M%S%N")
streamTimeStart=$(date -d "$timestamp21" +"%H%M%S%N")
streamTimeEnd=$(date -d "$timestamp22" +"%H%M%S%N")
```

Use epoch, its more sane

```
alertTime=$(date -d "$timestamp1" +"%s")
streamTimeStart=$(date -d "$timestamp21" +"%s")
streamTimeEnd=$(date -d "$timestamp22" +"%s")
```